# How do i Integrate an ecommerce website from a 3rd party onto my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I have a [Store](https://food.jumia.com.gh/shopping/g5xa/miniso-ghaha-limited/fashion-accessories-2038) on Jumia website where my products are listed. Jumia handles my checkouts for security purposes.

I, however, want to list the same products on [my website](https://miniso-gh.com/) and have the customers undertake all actions from my website (Wordpress Website).

How do i safely integrate the jumia store onto my website?

I know doing this via an iframe is not secure enough and I'm not sure how open Jumia's API's are and i cant redirect traffic to the Jumia Store.

Are there any alternatives (plugins) I could explore?

Comment: Install woocommerce on your Wordpress and see this plugin: https://cedcommerce.com/woocommerce-extensions/woocommerce-jumia-integration ... easy find on 10 secs googling